# How to navigate based on UserContext (lightning and classic)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, lightning-out

I have a lightning web component that displays accounts and contacts and allows navigation to them with the help of a button. I have used the LWC in lightning experience as well as in classic using lightning out. I used `if(UserContext === 'Theme4t' || UserContext === 'Theme4d')` to identify whether I am in Lightning or in classic. I will navigate based on UserContext. Problem is, I am getting UserContext as `undefined`. Hence I am not able to navigate in both lightning as well as in classic.

I passed the user context from the VF page as follows:

```js
<script>
    var myUserContext = "{!$User.UITheme}";
    $Lightning.use("c:lwcInVisualforceapp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:wrapperClassTestNavigation", {
            UserContext: myUserContext 
        },
        "lwcDemo",
            function(component) {
            }
       );
    });
    </script>
```

I access UserContext in javascript as follows:

```js
import { LightningElement,api,track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getWrapperLis from '@salesforce/apex/WrapperClass.getWrapperList';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation'; ///Navigation

export default class WrapperClassTestNavigation extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track columns = columns;
    @api UserContext;
    @wire(getWrapperLis,{}) wrappers;

    navigateToRecordViewPage(event,UserContext) {
        this.record = event.detail.row;
        if(UserContext !== undefined) {
            if(UserContext === 'Theme4t' || UserContext === 'Theme4d') {
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: this.record.id,
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                });
            } else {
                window.location.assign('/'+this.record.id);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

HTML:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="LWC Wrapper Component" icon-name="standard:contact">
        <div style="height: 400px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={wrappers.data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowaction={navigateToRecordViewPage}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>    
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use UserContext. Just replace the javascript function with this code:

```js
navigateToRecordViewPage(event) {
        this.record = event.detail.row;

        if(document.referrer.indexOf(".lightning.force.com") > 0){
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__recordPage',
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.record.id,
                    actionName: 'view'
                }
            });
        }else{
            window.location.assign('/'+this.record.id);
        }
    }
```